# Error while upgrading gpg (GnuPG) from 2.0.14 to 2.2 on Oracle Linux 6.4

Tags: upgrade, gnupg, oraclelinux

I am trying to upgrade gpg (GnuPG)  from  2.0.14 to 2.2 on Oracle Linux 6.4 x86_64
Downloaded latest version of gnupg and dependency library packages from below location.
https://gnupg.org/download/index.html
To install GPG and it's dependencies, below commands are run.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

"./configure" is run without any errors but errors are encountered while executing "make" and "make install" for dependency library pacakges "libgcrypt-1.8.6","libassuan-2.5.3" and "libksba-1.4.0".
Note: Dependency library packages "npth-1.6" and "libgpg-error-1.38" are installed without any errors.

Below is the error encountered.

```
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgcrypt.so.20" && ln -s "libgcrypt.so.20.2.6" "libgcrypt.so.20")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgcrypt.so" && ln -s "libgcrypt.so.20.2.6" "libgcrypt.so")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgcrypt.la" && ln -s "../libgcrypt.la" "libgcrypt.la" )
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wall   -o mpicalc mpicalc-mpicalc.o libgcrypt.la  -lgpg-error
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wall -o .libs/mpicalc mpicalc-mpicalc.o  ./.libs/libgcrypt.so -lgpg-error
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_ferror'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_fopenmem'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_lock_lock'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_lock_destroy'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_lock_unlock'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_lock_init'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpg_err_set_errno'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_rewind'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_fprintf'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_get_syscall_clamp'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_fclose'
./.libs/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_fclose_snatch'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [mpicalc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gpginstall/libgcrypt-1.8.6/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gpginstall/libgcrypt-1.8.6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Similar error is encountered with other library installation.

Is GPG2.2 supported on OracleLinux6.4 ? I am able to upgrade from GPG2.0 to 2.2 on RHEL7

Comment: I met a similar issue, any solution?

Comment: ++ same here using Amazon Linux2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the system libgpg-error package first.

Then configure and install libgpg-error from source. In a recent version, it will provide all the needed and otherwise missing symbols.